# I have set up an alertcondition on SPY, once triggered, how can it send me the price of another ticker like TSLA in PineScript?

Tags: pine-script

I'm using TradingView to follow the trend of the SPY index. Once its RSI fall out of range, I have set up a alertcondition to trigger the system to send me a message.

However, I can only find it send me the close price of the SPY, which is the ticker that I set up the alert on.

What I want to do is to ask the `alertcondition` function to send me the close price of another stock like TSLA.

I've tried to use `request.security`, but because it returns a series string, not a constant string, it can't be used in the message part.

Does anyone know how to use the alertcondition function to send another ticker's close price?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `securtiy()` together with the `alert()` function.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

c_sec = request.security("BINANCE:ETHUSDT", timeframe.period, close)

_s = "BTC: " + str.format("{0,number,#.##}", close) + "\nETH: " + str.format("{0,number,#.##}", c_sec)

alert(_s, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

[image]

Comment: No problem. If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it as an answer so we would know that this question has a valid answer.